# Caraousel in Angular JS which shows the current page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'v prepared a small carousel, which displays two images at a time. But, Also I need to show total number of pages like displaying small bubbles, which will enable the current page (like dot dot circles) at the bottom. I didn't get a proper one. Please let me know.

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/umswXrj8AgpK7T2dP9Pk?p=preview)

My code is

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap', 'angular-responsive']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.displayMode = 'mobile'; // default value


  $scope.$watch('displayMode', function(value) {

  switch (value) {
      case 'mobile':
        // do stuff for mobile mode
        console.log('Device :'+value);
      break;
      case 'tablet':
        // do stuff for tablet mode
      console.log('Device :'+value);
    break;
   }
  });
});
```

Rest of the code is available in Plunker.